# Training random forest (ranger) using caret with custom F1 metric in R yiels high f-scores but when doing actual predicting F1 score is low. How come?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, r-caret

I am trying to train a random forest model with ranger using caret's train function. I want to use the F1 score as the metric when training. The structure of my data is the following (there are not at all all variables - I just included a few - but basically all the response variables look the same - they are factor variables with 5 classes):

```
structure(list(q6_3 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Meget.utilfreds", 
    "Neutral", "Utilfreds", "Tilfreds", "Meget.tilfreds"), class = "factor"), 
    q6_4 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("Meget.utilfreds", 
    "Utilfreds", "Meget.tilfreds", "Neutral", "Tilfreds"), class = "factor"), 
    q6_5 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Neutral", 
    "Meget.utilfreds", "Utilfreds", "Tilfreds", "Meget.tilfreds"
    ), class = "factor"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am looping through a certain amount of variables as the outcome variable. Here is the functioning loop:

```
#define f1 score function for caret to train with f1 as the metric score
f1 <- function(data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) {
  f1_val <- MLmetrics::F1_Score(y_pred = data$pred,
                                y_true = data$obs,
                                positive = lev[1])
  c(F1 = f1_val)
}


#define a f1 score function to check the f1 score when applying the model to predict on the test set
f1_score <- function(predicted, expected, positive.class="1") {
  predicted <- factor(as.character(predicted), levels=unique(as.character(expected)))
  expected  <- as.factor(expected)
  cm = as.matrix(table(expected, predicted))
  
  precision <- diag(cm) / colSums(cm)
  recall <- diag(cm) / rowSums(cm)
  f1 <-  ifelse(precision + recall == 0, 0, 2 * precision * recall / (precision + recall))
  
  #Assuming that F1 is zero when it's not possible compute it
  f1[is.na(f1)] <- 0
  
  #Binary F1 or Multi-class macro-averaged F1
  ifelse(nlevels(expected) == 2, f1[positive.class], mean(f1))
}

# list for outcome variable (with names)
mylist.names <- holdnings_var
y_list <- vector("list", length(mylist.names))
names(y_list) <- mylist.names


# list for the predicted classes
pred_class <- vector("list", length(mylist.names))
names(pred_class) <- mylist.names


# list for the predicted probabilities
pred_prob <- vector("list", length(mylist.names))
names(pred_prob) <- mylist.names

# list for the models
rf_models <- vector("list", length(mylist.names))
names(rf_models) <- mylist.names


# dataframe to store the variable name and the results (f1 scores)
results <- as_tibble(data.frame(matrix(nrow=1,ncol=length(mylist.names))))
colnames(results) <- mylist.names




# Loop over training and predicting and store the f1 score values  --------
traincntr <- trainControl(method = "cv", 
                          number = 5,
                          search = "grid",  
                          verboseIter = TRUE,
                          summaryFunction = f1,
                          classProbs = TRUE,
                          allowParallel = TRUE)

tuning_grid_rf <- expand.grid(mtry = seq(30,35, by = 1),
                              splitrule = "gini", 
                              min.node.size = c(1))






set.seed(128)
cl <- makeCluster(8, setup_strategy = "sequential") # Change "8" to the number of cores on your computer
registerDoParallel(cl)

for (i in seq_along(holdnings_var)) {
  
  
  var <- holdnings_var[i]
  
  
  y_list[[var]] <- train_data_2[, (colnames(train_data_2) %in% var)]
  
  predictors <- train_data_2[, !(colnames(train_data_2) %in% var)]
  
  fit_rf <-  caret::train(y = y_list[[var]],
                          x = predictors,
                          method = 'ranger',
                          metric = "F1",
                          tuneGrid = tuning_grid_rf,         
                          trControl = traincntr,
                          importance = "permutation",
                          verbose = TRUE)
  
  
  
  rf_models[[var]] <- fit_rf
  
  pred_class[[var]] <-   predict.train(rf_models[[var]], test_data_2, type = "raw")
  pred_prob[[var]] <-   predict.train(rf_models[[var]], test_data_2, type = "prob")

  
  
  results[, (colnames(results) %in% var)] <- f1_score(pred_class[[var]], 
                                                      test_data_2[, (colnames(test_data_2) %in% var)])
  
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

When looking at the rf_models, the f1 scores look like the following. I am only showing a few here, as the model itself trains on 30 different predictors - which may be a bit overkill to show here.

Here for variable "q18"

```
$q18
Random Forest 

7347 samples
  44 predictor
   5 classes: 'Helt.sikkert.ikke', 'Nok.ikke', 'Neutral', 'Sikkert', 'Helt.sikkert' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (5 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 5879, 5878, 5878, 5876, 5877 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mtry  F1       
  10    0.7994885
  11    0.8021255
  12    0.8031557
  13    0.8036235
  14    0.8021628
  15    0.8029140
  16    0.8016948
  17    0.8020750
  18    0.8030643
  19    0.8029144
  20    0.8048152
```

Here for variable "q6_3"

```
$q6_3
Random Forest 

7347 samples
  44 predictor
   5 classes: 'Meget.utilfreds', 'Neutral', 'Utilfreds', 'Tilfreds', 'Meget.tilfreds' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (5 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 5875, 5879, 5879, 5877, 5878 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mtry  F1       
  10    0.7259594
  11    0.7250570
  12    0.7260447
  13    0.7255713
  14    0.7266375
  15    0.7266593
  16    0.7245010
  17    0.7273890
  18    0.7277144
  19    0.7267672
  20    0.7275720
```

This indicates that the model training has been able to reach a rather favorable F-score. However, when looking macro f-scores of the actual predictions, the picture is completely different:

```
  # arrange by highest f1 score
    results <- results %>% 
      pivot_longer(cols = c(1:30), 
                   names_to = "variable", 
                   values_to = "f1_macro_score")
    
 

> results_2 %>%
+   arrange(desc(f1_macro_score))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  variable f1_macro_score
  <chr>             <dbl>
1 q18               0.382
2 q6_1              0.282
3 q6_3              0.243
4 q5_1              0.225
5 q5_2              0.216
```

I only showed the rf models for the two variables q18 and q6_3. Meanwhile, writing this post I realized that the model for the variable "q6_1" (which achieved a macro_f1 score of 0.282) had a really low f-score while training:

```
$q6_1
Random Forest 

mtry  F1        
  10    0.04444444
  11    0.04444444
  12    0.04444444
  13    0.08510638
  14    0.04444444
  15    0.04396135
  16    0.04301573
  17    0.08296362
  18    0.04347826
  19    0.04349197
  20    0.04301573
```

But this is more the exception than the rule. Out of the 30 variables I trained, the f1 score while trained reached around 0.8 to 0.9, while the highest average macro f1 score when doing the actual predicting is only 0.3.

I am now wondering several things: What is wrong here?

Is the function for the f1 score (used in the training in carets trainControl - so the one I call when summaryFunction = f1) wrong? Or simply different than the function "f1_score" which I use to evaluate how good the predictions where? Or is the function "f1_score" itself wrong?

Is f1 score simply a bad evaluation metric when doing multiclass classification? Or is the problem that the classes are unbalanced? As one can see when applying a confusion matrix to for instance variable q6_1:

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

                 Reference
Prediction        Meget.tilfreds Meget.utilfreds Neutral Utilfreds Tilfreds
  Meget.tilfreds               2               0       0         2        0
  Meget.utilfreds             44            1352     183        85       39
  Neutral                      2              16      46         3        3
  Utilfreds                    6               4       4        21        1
  Tilfreds                     0               1       1         2       18

Overall Statistics
                                          
               Accuracy : 0.7842          
                 95% CI : (0.7647, 0.8028)
    No Information Rate : 0.7482          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.0001732       
                                          
                  Kappa : 0.2784

Statistics by Class:

                     Class: Meget.tilfreds Class: Meget.utilfreds Class: Neutral Class: Utilfreds Class: Tilfreds
Sensitivity                        0.03704                 0.9847        0.19658          0.18584        0.295082
Specificity                        0.99888                 0.2403        0.98501          0.99129        0.997745
Pos Pred Value                     0.50000                 0.7939        0.65714          0.58333        0.818182
Neg Pred Value                     0.97160                 0.8409        0.89348          0.94886        0.976282
Precision                          0.50000                 0.7939        0.65714          0.58333        0.818182
Recall                             0.03704                 0.9847        0.19658          0.18584        0.295082
F1                                 0.06897                 0.8791        0.30263          0.28188        0.433735
Prevalence                         0.02943                 0.7482        0.12752          0.06158        0.033243
Detection Rate                     0.00109                 0.7368        0.02507          0.01144        0.009809
Detection Prevalence               0.00218                 0.9281        0.03815          0.01962        0.011989
Balanced Accuracy                  0.51796                 0.6125        0.59080          0.58856        0.646414
```

If this is the issue, I also heard something about doing a weighted f1-metric. If this is the reason, how can this be done using caret?

Answer (score 0):

```
> f1 <- function(data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) {
  f1_val <- MLmetrics::F1_Score(y_pred = data$pred,
                                y_true = data$obs,
                                positive = lev[1])
  c(F1 = f1_val)
}
```

Here, positive = lev[1] indicates 1st level of response variable as positive . Right?